# OpenCV and OsX HEAD detection

Tags: macos, opencv

Im looking to create a program that detects HEADS with opencv, not just faces. There must be a way to do this. Besides heads, I need to identify the most high pixel of the head (the top part of the hair) and the low center point of the chin... I'm not finding any OS X OpenCV examples.. Here is a picture of what I'd like to achieve...https://pasteboard.co/GF19Fao.jpg

Looks simple enough right?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into [haarcascades](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#cascadeclassifier) for this.

[This](http://alereimondo.no-ip.org/OpenCV/34.version?id=60) consists of a couple cascades not included in [OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades).

---

**Method 1:**

The *profile* and *frontal face* ones are a good starting point.

Personally, I have not tested them yet so it is hard for me to tell you what the results look like.

If the final bounding box fits *perfectly* over the entire head alone, then you can make the following assumptions as a starting point

```
if box = (topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight)
then hairTop = distance(topLeft, topRight)/2
and chin = distance(bottomLeft, bottomRight)/2
```

If not you could do two things:

**1.** Make some measurement readjustments to see how far up or down to move the resulting rectangle in order to find the chin and top hair.

**2.** You could use a combination of other classifiers as well.

Combine the results of the *front/profile face* with the *mouth* classifier to find the chin

Combine the *front/profile face* with *upperbody* classifier to find the top hair.

---

**Method 2**

You could also use the *front/profile face* classifiers to find the top hair and just use *mouth* to find the chin.

---

Either methods require that you run multiple tests to find the optimal values/estimates that fulfill your task.

Comment: By the way.. Every picture I use will have the face in the same place

Comment: Yes. I managed to get the mouth part down. I found a "head to shoulders" cascade but it sometimes shows more than the hair at the top.. i need to exactly match the top of the hair. Can you explain your "hair top" algorithm for me ?

Comment: @DavidKachlon Its not a concrete one and was meant to be a starter point. It used the profile/face cascade. I'd recommend u combine the results of the profile/face and head/shoulders cascade to find the `hairTop`. Can u post a pic of the results of both cascades together?